# Boundaries- regularity and local parametrization

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with $C^2$ boundary.Let $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$. We choose a $X_1,x_2,x_3$- coordinate system such that the $x_1,x_2$-plane is tangential to $\partial \Omega$ at $x_0$ and such that the exterior normal vector at $x_0$ points into the negative $x_3$ axis. For $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we write $x'=(x_1,x_2)$. By our choice of the coordinate system we have $x=(x',x_3),\  x_0=(x_0',0)$.
Now the problematic part, which I dont't understand:
Since $\partial \Omega \in C^2$ a parametrization of a neighborhood $V_R=V_R(x_0) \subseteq \partial \Omega$ of $x_0$ in $\partial \Omega$ is given by $y' \mapsto (y',\phi(y')):B'_R \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to V_R$, where $ B'_R = (y' \in \mathbb{R}^2  \ | \ |y'-x_0'| < R)  $ and where $\phi \in C^2(B_R',\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $|\phi(y')| \leq M |y'-x_0'|^2$, $|\nabla \phi(y')| \leq M' |y'-x_0'|$, with suitable constants $M, M' >0$ (which are independent of $x_0$.
It is not clear for me, that such parametrization could be chosen (also with those estimates). I only read the definition of a $C^k$ boundary in Evans "Partial differential equations", which does not immediately imply the above mentioned fact.
Greetings, David